# php outputting code rather than executing

Tags: php, html, mysql

I am pretty new to php, but have to link a database to html through php as part of uni coursework, so I attempted to implement a register and log in feature to the site we created. As far as I am aware this code should work however whenever I try to run it through the html page it posts the code itself rather than running. This is the case for both the login and registration. What am I doing wrong?

```
//registration
<?php 
    define('DB_HOST', 'xxx'); 
    define('DB_NAME', 'xxx'); 
    define('DB_USER','xxx'); 
    define('DB_PASSWORD','xxx'); 

    $con = mysql_connect(DB_HOST,DB_USER,DB_PASSWORD) or die("Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysql_error());

    $db = mysql_select_db(DB_NAME,$con) or die("Failed to connect to MySQL Database: " . mysql_error()); 

function NewUser() { 
    $Name = $_POST['Name']; 
    $Username = $_POST['Username']; 
    $Email = $_POST['Email']; 
    $Password = $_POST['Password']; 

    $query = "INSERT INTO userDetails (Username,Email,Name,Password) VALUES  ('$Username','$Email','$Name','$Password')"; 

    $data = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());

    if($data) { 
        echo "YOUR REGISTRATION IS COMPLETED...";
    }
}

function SignUp()    { 
    if(!empty($_POST['Username'])) { 
        $query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM userDetails WHERE Username =   '$_POST[Username]' AND Password = '$_POST[Password]'") or die(mysql_error()); 

        if(!$row = mysql_fetch_array($query) or die(mysql_error())) {
            newuser(); 
        } else { 
            echo "YOU ARE ALREADY A REGISTERED USER..."; 
        } 
    } 
} 

if(isset($_POST['submit'])) { 
    SignUp();
}
```

Comment: Is it a `.php` file extension? If yes, is PHP installed and running properly? If yes... continue to step 3) Are you accessing as `http://localhost/file.php` or `file:///file.php`? If none of these worked, well I'm out of of ideas. Last ditch effort, if `.html`, did you instruct Apache to treat those as PHP?

Comment: I think it's one of cases @Fred-ii- said. From your "however whenever I try to run it through the html page" I believe your file doesn't use `.php` extension, and you propably don't even have PHP, along with Apache installed.

Comment: I edited your question's code. It seemed to look like actual login credentials, so I **strongly suggest** you go change your login credentials on that server **now** if those were in fact actual credentials.

Comment: thanks turns out i was trying to run it from the folder, it seems to be working now

Comment: You may as well delete the question and again, if those were actual login credentials, I hope they were not. If so, I hope you've changed them.

Comment: And now you know why you shouldn't have database configurations in publicly accessible places! (Hint: Put them outside of the docroot and `require` them!)